# Php regex issue symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In send mail function I have code for decoding header:

```
preg_match_all('/[\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177-\377]/', $str, $matches);
```

If in string is a symbol, for example `ä` (März) then it will return an empty string. Please help me, how can I fix it (for use with German symbols too)? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `/u` flag for unicode:

```
preg_match_all('/[\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177-\377]/u', $str, $matches);
#                                               here __^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `u` flag outside the delimiters:

```
$str="März";
preg_match_all('/[\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177-\377]/u', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

If your PHP file is encoded as UTF-8, you can also use special characters inside the pattern:

```
preg_match_all('/[Mäz]/u', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59da39f95a8f87e6317554d45a920cf38c4d065b).